# A dynamic string interface in C

Tags: c, strings, c11

So I've written up what the title says.

Obviously, I'm looking for speed, safety and ease of use. To achieve the perfect ratio I've made some functions straight away crash if the input is wrong (in debug mode only, otherwise UD). The design is inspired by the C++ counterpart.

Will be glad to hear other opinions. (It's a lot of code, so bear with me.)

### dynstring.h

```
#ifndef DYNSTRING_H
#define DYNSTRING_H

#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct {
    char* data;
    size_t size;
} string;

extern bool string_create(string*);
extern bool string_create_n(string*, size_t);
extern bool string_create_from_raw(string*, const char*);

extern void string_destroy(string*);

extern bool string_copy(string*, string);
extern bool string_copy_from_raw(string*, const char*);

extern void string_set(string*, size_t, char);
extern char string_get(string, size_t);

extern char* string_front(string);
extern char* string_back(string);

extern char* string_to_raw(string);

extern size_t string_size(string);
extern bool   string_empty(string);

extern void string_erase(string*, size_t, size_t);

extern bool string_push_back(string*, char);
extern bool string_push_front(string*, char);

extern bool string_pop_back(string*);
extern bool string_pop_front(string*);

extern bool string_append(string*, string);
extern bool string_append_raw(string*, const char*);

extern bool string_substr(string, size_t, size_t, string*);

extern void string_swap(string*, string*);
extern int  string_compare(string, string);

extern size_t string_find(string, char);
extern size_t string_find_substr(string, const char*);

#endif
```

### dynstring.c

```
#include "dynstring.h"

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

bool string_create(string* str)
{
    assert(str);
    // allocate 1 for '\0'
    str->data = malloc(sizeof(char));
    if (!str->data) {
        return false;
    }
    str->size = 0;
    str->data[0] = '\0';
    return true;
}

bool string_create_n(string* str, size_t size)
{
    assert(str);
    if (size == 0) {
        return string_create(str);
    }
    // one extra for '\0'
    str->data = malloc(sizeof(char) * size + 1);
    if (!str->data) {
        return false;
    }
    str->size = size;
    str->data[str->size] = '\0';
    return true;
}

bool string_create_from_raw(string* str, const char* from)
{
    assert(str && from);
    if (!string_create_n(str, strlen(from))) {
        return false;
    }
    memcpy(str->data, from, sizeof(char) * str->size);
    return true;
}

void string_destroy(string* str)
{
    assert(str);
    free(str->data);
}

bool string_copy(string* dest, string src)
{
    assert(dest);
    if (dest->size >= src.size) {
        memcpy(dest->data, src.data, sizeof(char) * src.size + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        char* temp = malloc(sizeof(char) * src.size + 1);
        if (!temp) {
            return false;
        }
        memcpy(temp, src.data, sizeof(char) * src.size + 1);
        free(dest->data);
        dest->data = temp;
    }
    dest->size = src.size;
    return true;
}

bool string_copy_from_raw(string* dest, const char* src)
{
    assert(dest && src);
    string str;
    if (!string_create_from_raw(&str, src)) {
        return false;
    }
    string_swap(&str, dest);
    string_destroy(&str);
    return true;
}

void string_set(string* str, size_t i, char c)
{
    assert(str && str->size > i);
    str->data[i] = c;
}

char string_get(string str, size_t i)
{
    assert(str.size > i);
    return str.data[i];
}

char* string_front(string str) {
    return str.data;
}

char* string_back(string str) {
    return str.data + str.size - 1;
}

// same as string_front
// exists only because it looks better
// to say puts(string_to_raw(str));
char* string_to_raw(string str) {
    return str.data;
}

size_t string_size(string str) {
    return str.size;
}

bool string_empty(string str) {
    return str.size;
}

// erases characters in range [i, i+n] including
void string_erase(string* str, size_t i, size_t n)
{
    assert(str && str->size > i);
    if (i + n > str->size) {
        str->size = i;
    }
    else if (n != 0)
    {
        memcpy(str->data + i, 
               str->data + i + n, 
               sizeof(char) * str->size - i + n);
        str->size -= n;
    }
    str->data[str->size] = 0;
}

bool string_push_back(string* str, char ch)
{
    assert(str);
    string temp;
    if (!string_create_n(&temp, str->size + 1)) {
        return false;
    }
    memcpy(temp.data, str->data, sizeof(char) * str->size);
    temp.data[temp.size - 1] = ch;
    string_swap(&temp, str);
    string_destroy(&temp);
    return true;
}

bool string_push_front(string* str, char ch)
{
    assert(str);
    string temp;
    if (!string_create_n(&temp, str->size + 1)) {
        return false;
    }
    memcpy(temp.data + 1, str->data, sizeof(char) * str->size);
    temp.data[0] = ch;
    string_swap(&temp, str);
    string_destroy(&temp);
    return true;
}

bool string_pop_back(string* str)
{
    assert(str && str->size != 0);
    --str->size;
    str->data[str->size] = 0;
    return true;
}

bool string_pop_front(string* str)
{
    assert(str && str->size != 0);
    string temp;
    if (!string_create_from_raw(&temp, str->data + 1)) {
        return false;
    }
    string_destroy(str);
    string_swap(&temp, str);
    return true;
}

bool string_append(string* str, string toapp)
{
    assert(str);
    string temp;
    if (!string_create_n(&temp, str->size + toapp.size)) {
        return false;
    }
    memcpy(temp.data, str->data, str->size);
    memcpy(temp.data + str->size, toapp.data, toapp.size);
    string_swap(&temp, str);
    string_destroy(&temp);
    return true;
}

bool string_append_raw(string* str, const char* toapp)
{
    assert(str && toapp);
    size_t len = strlen(toapp);
    string temp;
    if (!string_create_n(&temp, str->size + len)) {
        return false;
    }
    memcpy(temp.data, str->data, str->size);
    memcpy(temp.data + str->size, toapp, len);
    string_swap(&temp, str);
    string_destroy(&temp);
    return true;
}

// puts the substring from index i to index j into 'to'
bool string_substr(string from, size_t i, size_t j, string* to)
{
    assert(i < j && j < from.size && to);
    string temp;
    if (!string_create_n(&temp, j - i + 1)) {
        return false;
    }
    memcpy(temp.data, from.data + i, j - i + 1);
    string_swap(&temp, to);
    string_destroy(&temp);
    return true;
}

void string_swap(string* lhs, string* rhs)
{
    assert(lhs && rhs);

    char* data = lhs->data;
    lhs->data = rhs->data;
    rhs->data = data;

    size_t size = lhs->size;
    lhs->size = rhs->size;
    rhs->size = size;
}

int string_compare(string lhs, string rhs) {
    return strcmp(lhs.data, rhs.data);
}

size_t string_find(string str, char c)
{
    char* find = strchr(str.data, c);
    if (!find) {
        return (size_t)-1;
    }
    return (size_t)(find - str.data);
}

size_t string_find_substr(string str, const char* tofind)
{
    assert(tofind);
    char* find = strstr(str.data, tofind);
    if (!find) {
        return (size_t)-1;
    }
    return (size_t)(find - str.data);
}
```

Comment: Real C++ string will exponentially increase in size. You'll need to keep a capacity for that, or you could check for null terminator. If you want extreme optimizations, there are two paths to choose from: prepend the metadata right before the string on the heap, or use small object optimization (create a union that will be either {char* data, size_t size, size_t capacity} or char[24]). The latter also has some more optimizations, but they are much harder to implement.

Comment: @Incomputable Yes, thanks for the comment. I had considered both optimizations, but thought it wouldn't be too fun to upload 500 lines up here... People wouldn't bother I guess.

Comment: One immediately obvious problem is that your identifiers all begin with `str`.  All identifiers beginning with `str` are reserved for future Standard Library extension.

Comment: @Toby Do you have a reference at hand?

Comment: Not normative, but see [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/identifier#Reserved_identifiers).  (Yes, C++ Reference also has good notes on C, too!)

Comment: @Toby Well, what comes to mind is using _handles_ rather than direct pointers.

Comment: §7.31.12 of the C11 standard if anyone wants to look. This also means "is" followed by a lowercase is reserved, which is absurd...

Comment: It's handy to keep the size and data in one place: `struct {size_t size; char data[];}`. You'll save some trouble with double allocation / freeing and also one dereference.

Answer (score 2):

## Improvements

#### Initializing functions (string_create*)

I think it's a common practice that initializing functions return whole structure element. For example, your implementation

```
extern bool string_create_n(string* str, size_t size);
```

should look like this

```
extern string * string_create_n(size_t size);
```

It's also applicable to free/destroy function - this function should destroy whole object (not just data).

#### Try realloc before malloc

Let's say you calling `string_push_back` function, so it basically means that you would like to add one more character to the data. Instead of using malloc in a first place I would suggest to try to extend current array by one `sizeof(char)` using [realloc](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_realloc.htm). I also introduced one more variable to the structure - `size_t alloc_size` keeps actual size of allocated memory. It allows to avoid frequent reallocations events (there is invariant that `alloc_size >= size + 1`).

#### Be careful with Memory leaks

Your code contains a lot of problems with memory management. For example

```
bool string_create(string* str)
{
    assert(str);
    // allocate 1 for '\0'
    str->data = malloc(sizeof(char));
    if (!str->data) {
        return false;
    }
    str->size = 0;
    str->data[0] = '\0';
    return true;
}
```

Imagine that there is an allocated array in `str->data`. By making malloc before freeing, you losing link to the first array.

---

## Suggestions

1. I prefer to use const modifier as much as possible. There are
   [numerous benefits](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/204500/when-and-for-what-purposes-should-the-const-keyword-be-used-in-c-for-variables) to follow this advice.
2. Thanks to  @toby-speight' comment I get to know that identifier [should not](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/identifier#Reserved_identifiers) start from reserved word like `str`.

---

## TODO List

1. You should remove assert and write meaningful error messages. Instead of returning bool value, use int values which should be macro-defined.
2. dyn_string_push_front and dyn_string_pop_front are implemented not-optimally.
3. <s>Structure dyn_string contains size of the data, so you can skip '\0' ending. It's good idea because, first, you will save memory and, second, you will avoid actions related to '\0' maintenance.</s>

   ---

## My version

### dynstring.c

```
#include "dynstring.h"
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

dyn_string* dyn_string_alloc(const size_t n)
{
    dyn_string *p;
    assert(n);
    p = (dyn_string *) malloc (sizeof (dyn_string));
    assert(p);
    p->data = (char *) malloc (n * sizeof (char));
    assert(p->data);
    p->size = 0;
    p->data[0] = '\0';
    p->alloc_size = n;
    return p;
}

void dyn_string_realloc(dyn_string * p, const size_t n)
{
    char *c;
    assert(p);
    if (n > p->alloc_size) {
        c = (char *) realloc(p->data, sizeof(char) * n);
        if(c == 0) {
            c = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * n);
            assert(c);
            memcpy(c, p->data, sizeof(char) * (p->size + 1));
            free(p->data);
            p->data = c;
        } 
        p->alloc_size = n;
    }
}

dyn_string* dyn_string_alloc_raw(const char* src)
{
    size_t n = strlen(src) + 1;
    dyn_string *p = dyn_string_alloc(n);
    assert(p);
    memcpy(p->data, src, sizeof(char) * n);
    p->size = n - 1;
    return p;
}

dyn_string* dyn_string_alloc_cpy(const dyn_string * src)
{
    assert(src);
    size_t n = src->size + 1;
    dyn_string *p = dyn_string_alloc(n);
    memcpy(p->data, src->data, sizeof(char) * n);
    p->size = src->size;
    p->alloc_size = n;
    return p;
}

void dyn_string_free(dyn_string * p)
{
    assert(p);
    free(p->data);
    free(p);
}

void dyn_string_cpy(dyn_string * dst, const dyn_string * src)
{
    assert(dst && src);
    size_t n = src->size + 1;
    if (dst->alloc_size < n) {
        dyn_string_realloc(dst, n);
    }
    memcpy(dst->data, src->data, sizeof(char) * n);
    dst->size = src->size;
}

void dyn_string_cpy_raw(dyn_string* dst, const char* src)
{
    assert(dst && src);
    size_t n = strlen(src) + 1;
    if (dst->alloc_size < n) {
        dyn_string_realloc(dst, n);
    }
    memcpy(dst->data, src, sizeof(char) * n);
    dst->size = n - 1;
}

void dyn_string_set(dyn_string* p, const size_t i, const char c)
{
    assert(p && p->size > i);
    p->data[i] = c;
}

char dyn_string_get(const dyn_string* p, const size_t i)
{
    assert(p->size > i);
    return p->data[i];
}

char* dyn_string_front(const dyn_string * p) {
    return p->data;
}

char* dyn_string_back(const dyn_string * p) {
    return p->data + p->size;
}

size_t dyn_string_size(const dyn_string * p) {
    return p->size;
}

// erases characters iddn range [i, i+n] including
void dyn_string_erase(dyn_string* p, const size_t i, const size_t n)
{
    assert(p && p->size > i);
    if (i + n + 1 >= p->size) {
        p->size = i;
    } else {
        p->size -= (n + 1);
        memcpy(p->data + i,
               p->data + i + n + 1,
               sizeof(char) * (p->size - i));
    } 
    p->data[p->size] = '\0';
}

void dyn_string_push_back(dyn_string* p, const char c)
{
    assert(p);
    if (p->size + 1 <= p->alloc_size) {
        dyn_string_realloc(p, p->alloc_size<<1);
    }
    p->data[p->size++] = c;
    p->data[p->size] = '\0';
}

void dyn_string_push_front(dyn_string* p, const char c)
{
    assert(p);
    if (p->size + 1 <= p->alloc_size) {
        dyn_string_realloc(p, p->alloc_size<<1);
    }
    p->size++;
    memcpy(p->data + 1, p->data, sizeof(char) * p->size); //Not optimal
    p->data[0] = c;
}

char dyn_string_pop_back(dyn_string* p)
{
    assert(p && p->size != 0); 
    p->size--;
    char c = p->data[p->size];
    p->data[p->size] = '\0';
    return c;
}

char dyn_string_pop_front(dyn_string* p)
{
    assert(p && p->size != 0);
    char c = p->data[0];
    memcpy(p->data, p->data + 1, sizeof(char) * p->size--); //Not optimal
    return c;
}

void dyn_string_append(dyn_string* dst, const dyn_string* src)
{
    assert(src && dst);
    size_t n = dst->size + src->size + 1;
    if (dst->alloc_size < n) {
        dyn_string_realloc(dst, n);
    }
    memcpy(dst->data + dst->size, src->data, sizeof(char) * (src->size + 1));
    dst->size = n - 1;
}

void dyn_string_append_raw(dyn_string* dst, const char* src)
{
    assert(src && dst);
    size_t l = strlen(src) + 1;
    size_t n = l + dst->size;
    if (dst->alloc_size < n) {
        dyn_string_realloc(dst, n);           
    }   
    memcpy(dst->data + dst->size, src, sizeof(char) * l);
    dst->size = n - 1;
}

// copy substr iddn range [i, i+n] including
void dyn_string_substr(dyn_string * dst, const dyn_string * src, const size_t i, const size_t n)
{
    assert(dst && src && i + n < src->size);
    size_t n0 = n + 1;
    if (dst->alloc_size < n0) {
        dyn_string_realloc(dst, n0);
    }
    memcpy(dst->data, src->data + i, sizeof(char) * n0);
    dst->size = n;
}

void dyn_string_swap(dyn_string* p0, dyn_string* p1)
{
    assert(p0 && p1);
    dyn_string * p = p0;
    p0 = p1;
    p1 = p;
}

int dyn_string_compare(const dyn_string* p0, const dyn_string* p1) 
{
    assert(p0 && p1);
    return (p0->size != p1->size) ? (p0->size - p1->size) : strcmp(p0->data, p1->data);
}

size_t dyn_string_find(const dyn_string* src, const char c)
{
    assert(src);
    char *p;
    return (p = strchr(src->data, c)) ? (p - src->data) : (size_t)-1;
}

size_t dyn_string_find_substr(const dyn_string* big, const char* small)
{
    assert(big && small);
    char *p;
    return (p = strstr(big->data, small)) ? (p-big->data) : (size_t)-1;
}
```

### dynstring.h

```
#ifndef DYNSTRING_H
#define DYNSTRING_H

#include <stddef.h>

typedef struct {
    char* data;
    size_t size;
    size_t alloc_size;
} dyn_string;

extern dyn_string* dyn_string_alloc(const size_t);
extern void dyn_string_realloc(dyn_string*, const size_t);
extern dyn_string* dyn_string_alloc_raw(const char*);
extern dyn_string* dyn_string_alloc_cpy(const dyn_string*);

extern void dyn_string_free(dyn_string*);

extern void dyn_string_cpy(dyn_string*, const dyn_string*);
extern void dyn_string_cpy_raw(dyn_string*, const char*);

extern void dyn_string_set(dyn_string*, const size_t, const char);
extern char dyn_string_get(const dyn_string*, const size_t);

extern char* dyn_string_front(const dyn_string*);
extern char* dyn_string_back(const dyn_string*);

extern size_t dyn_string_size(const dyn_string*);
extern void dyn_string_erase(dyn_string*, const size_t, const size_t);

extern void dyn_string_push_back(dyn_string*, const char);
extern void dyn_string_push_front(dyn_string*, const char);

extern char dyn_string_pop_back(dyn_string*);
extern char dyn_string_pop_front(dyn_string*);

extern void dyn_string_append(dyn_string*, const dyn_string*);
extern void dyn_string_append_raw(dyn_string*, const char*);

extern void dyn_string_substr(dyn_string*, const dyn_string *, const size_t, const size_t);

extern void dyn_string_swap(dyn_string*, dyn_string*);
extern int  dyn_string_compare(const dyn_string*, const dyn_string*);

extern size_t dyn_string_find(const dyn_string*, const char);
extern size_t dyn_string_find_substr(const dyn_string*, const char*);

#endif
```

Comment: `assert.h` doesn't belong into `dynstring.h`.

Comment: @RolandIllig Yes, I agree. I changed files

Comment: If you omit the `'\0'`, how will you use the string? Pretty much all string-related functions like `printf` etc. need the `'\0'`. Also note that you should use `memmove` for overlapping data, which does exactly the same thing as OP's implementation – it uses a temporary buffer.

Comment: @kyrill honestly, in my first version I tried to omit '\0' but I gave up than I realized  that instead of `strstr` I should use `memmem`. Well, actually printf [can work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137779/how-do-i-print-a-non-null-terminated-string-using-printf) with non-null terminated strings.

Comment: OK, what if I wanted to use `puts` instead? Or what if I wanted to use this dynamic string as the formatting string for `printf`?

Comment: @kyrill, I have a general feeling that non-null terminated sting is like to nail "[Ninety-five Theses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Luther)" on the K&R book. But as you understand I was confused by the redundancy of information. Maybe there is no point of the variable `size`...

Comment: `size` can be useful if you need it often, especially when the strings are long since it's \$O(n)\$ time to calculate the length.

Comment: Note that dereferencing the pointer returned by your version of `dyn_string_alloc` invokes undefined behavior because it points to a local variable.  See [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6441218).  In fact, the new interface should return a non-pointer.  Alternatively, just stick with the original version.

Answer (score 1):

This module is intended to be written once, never changed again, right? Also, you strive for efficiency? Then put everything in the header. As currently used `extern` [does nothing](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter4/linkage.html). Replace it with inline and put the definitions there. You can still move the declarations tothe top of the file, for client convenience.

Secondly, one more vote for small object optimization. The heap is insanely expensive (could reach 1000 cycles for a single allocation). If portability is not important, usa `alloca()`.

Drop the bool returns. In my experience, no one checks error codes. And most errors you report can almost never happen. `malloc` fails? There is something **very wrong** with the system. Blow an assert or `exit(1)`. What is a caller supposed to do with a failed malloc? Try to malloc again?

Comment: _"Blow an assert or exit(1)"_. Yeah why not `system('poweroff')`...

Comment: if your system has 0% physical memory, a power off could be a sensible approach.